# Simple Unconstrained Optimisation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

Question (True or False)

Suppose $f(x,y)=(x-y)^2 + (x+y)^4$. It attains the global minimum at (0,0).

---

A few questions regarding this question.

i)   $|D^2f(0,0)|=0$, so the second derivative test is useless?

ii) Is there any quick way to check for convexness/concaveness without going back to definition?(Only for 2 variables). For example, am I wrong to conclude that, because $x^2 -2xy +y^2 + (x^2 + 2xy +y^2)^2$ consists of the sum of convex functions, $f$ is convex.

iii) The lecturer's solution said $f$ is concave, is it a typo?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. If your calculations were correct, yes, the second derivative test doesn't help. 2. A sum of convex (respectively concave) is convex (respectively concave). As for the original question, it is easy to see that $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for every $x,y$, and $0$ is attained at $(0,0)$. So $(0,0)$ is a global minimizer. Is it unique?

Comment: As @Ian alludes, you may want to [double check your work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D+[+D[+%28x-y%29^2+%2B+%28x%2By%29^4+%2C+x+%2C+y]+%2C+x%2C+y]).

Comment: @user1717828 , is that expression you provided the same as the determinant of the Hessian matrix?

Comment: @user1717828, I got really confused. I am pretty sure It's 0. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%28x-y%29%5E2%2B%28x%2By%29%5E4%2C+%7B%7Bx%2C+y%7D%7D%2C+%7B%7Bx%2C+y%7D%7D%5D

Comment: @Cheuk, I have no idea about the Hessian matrix, but I believe if you want to know whether the function is concave up or concave down (or a saddle point) at `(0,0)`, you need to take $\partial_x\partial_x\partial_y\partial_yf(x,y)$, which I did for you in the last link.  If that is incorrect, then I apologize for not understanding your question and needlessly complicating it.

Comment: @user1717828, oh no worry. I just don't know your method for discerning the concaveness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the concavity of a function $f(x)$ at some point $x_0$ by taking its double derivative with respect to $x$ and plugging $x=x_0$ in the result:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)\right]_{x=x_0}$$

In your case, you have a function $f(x,y)$, so you have to take derivatives of *both* variables - a total of *four* derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)\right]\right]\right]_{x=x_0, y=y_0},$$

which [evaluates to a positive constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D+%5B+D%5B+%28x-y%29%5E2+%2B+%28x%2By%29%5E4+%2C+x+%2C+y%5D+%2C+x%2C+y%5D), determining the function $f(x,y)$ at the point $(0,0)$ is ***concave up***.